# Symfony Web Notifications

Tags: symfony, vue.js, websocket, socket.io, web-notifications

I am using Symfony 4.2 + vue.js on my website. I want to send web notifications (not browser notifications) something similar to Podio / Facebook notifications. I had searched socket.io but since it is node I think I cant use it with Symfony.
Not only that am using yarn server.

Can you guys please suggest me an idea, how can I implement it?

Comment: If you want to implement a websocket connection with a PHP backend, Ratchet might be useful http://socketo.me/ I implemented in the past a real time web app with Ratchet and Symfony (2.8) and it worked great (yeah, I know, node.js could be a better option for Real Time App but it was a client requirement... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ratchet, it's quite simple. I had implemented it in Symfony, it has simple documentation which helps to code faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Web worker/Service workers with the Push API to achieve this

The Push API permit to send push notifications even when your website is down or 0 tabs of your site are opened.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API

Basically you need to register a new service worker, then send information from your Symfony Backend app or from VueJS and then push the new notification

You have a complete [exemple here](https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple_demo.html) with some code.

**EDIT**

If you want to make Facebook like inside app notification, you should implement https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify and re-work the nofitications template to show them like you want

If you want to use SocketIO with Symfony there is https://packagist.org/packages/wisembly/elephant.io that allow that. You need, I think, use Docker to have your nodejs/socketio server and your actual app.

You can even try with [Mecure protocol](https://github.com/dunglas/mercure) (a symfony integration exist) to made you app push notification/data on the mercure hub and then automatically (in real time) display them on your Vue app.

**EDIT 2**

The way I use in my Symfony web site actually (need to be rework with real time tool but working well) is to create a DB table that will store all the notifications, and then with JS check every X time with there is a new entry on the notifiactions table, using AJAX and custom Symfony controller.

Comment: I think it is for Browser Notifications, i want notifications similar to Facebook or podio

Comment: Inside app notification like Facebook notification tab ?

Comment: Yes, inside my website along with the count

Comment: @XavierIssac I add the way I use actually in our Symfony/Vue app

Comment: Actually snotify will only act as alert, we cant use it here :)